Installing Spring close hinges if reveal is small
I have a glass inside wood frame door that leads to our backyard and pool and it has regular hinges on it. I am wanting to upgrade the hinges to be spring close similar to our garage door but it looks to me like the reveal on the back door is only 1/4 of an inch and the gauge door has a larger 3/8 reveal that can accommodate the larger barrel on the spring close hinges.  Any solutions - such as super slim spring hinges? - other than what I think is the only solution, to remove the trim and move it over 1/8th.  That of course ends up with lots of work to get the door back to a nice appearance (glossy spray on the trim, some patching, and  plastic wood filling where the 1/8 gap is revealed on the header board). Not to mention if the trim doesn't remove well of if I can't knife out the 1/8 on the baseboard etc.



Are you attached to barrel hinges for some reason?  There are all kinds of self closing door hinges, low profile or invisible.  Or use a storm door closer or a commercial door closer.

IDK how these compare to yours, but I have these installed on a couple of doors. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07GDS15KG  These may be fatter than yours, but you get what you get.

On the wood frame door it may not need any change in the size of the reveal. Instead it would be normal to make the hinge mortise cutout a bit deeper in both the door edge and the door frame to accommodate the thicker hinge plates on the spring hinge.
An alternative that I've used on the door between my house and garage is to install a commercial style door closer. I did this after two sets of spring hinges had failed over a period of years, most likely not being capable of dealing with the rather heavy weight door. The closer was rather expensive but has served very well for 7 years now and should last much longer. A closer is somewhat adjustable and lets the door close softer than the spring hinges which slammed the door shut with a loud bang every time.

Picture source

Barrel hinges in black match all the other hardware in the house and the trim and hang. Also the door has a Hunter Douglas automated shade on the top so the more commercial looking closets won’t work as far a I know or will not work with the look.

@WilliamHenry -- continuing with Karas' theme, concealed (in frame or in door) mount closers such as the LCN 2010 & 3130 are available from architectural suppliers...
